# Android: Use progress dialog till a new activity loads up

Tags: java, android, exception, bluetooth

I am trying to connect to a bluetooth device(BLE HC05 module) using my app, to do some IOT functionality

Below snippet shows the code which is used to go to a new activity when user clicks on a particular device to connect to.

This is in BluetoothActivity.java

```
lvPairedDevices.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            final Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothActivity.this, TemperatureActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Bluetooth Device Address", mBTPairedDevices.get(position).getAddress());
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

As it is mentioned, I am sending the Bluetooth device's MAC Address. Using it an attempt to connect to the device is made.

This is in TemperatureActivity.java

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
deviceAddress = extras.getString("Bluetooth Device Address");
bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);

try {
        btSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        btSocket.connect();

        if(btSocket.isConnected())
            Toast.makeText(TemperatureActivity.this,"Connected to " + device.getName() + " successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(TemperatureActivity.this,"Couldn\'t connect to " + device.getName() + " properly", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
        connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(btSocket);
        connectedThread.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume: Bluetooth device could not be connected using RFCOMM");
        Toast.makeText(TemperatureActivity.this, "Connection to device " + device.getName() + " using RFCOMM has failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
```

According to the above code, if the device is offline or has declined to connect, an exception will arise.

**With the current situation, is there any possibility of using Progress dialog in the BluetoothActivity.java and stop it in both cases(bluetooth connection is established successfully or not) in TemperatureActivity.java**

I will go to TemperatureActivity with the device's MAC address, if it is successful in connecting to the device it should stay in that page(TemperatureActivity) otherwise, return to the original page (BluetoothActivity) saying "Couldn't connect to the device"

I searched a lot, could not find an answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you really trying to achieve here? you don't want to start TemperatureActivity if the connection is not successful?

Comment: I will go to TemperatureActivity with the device's MAC address, if it is successful in connecting to the device it should stay in that page(TemperatureActivity) otherwise, return to the original page (BluetoothActivity) saying "Couldn't connect to the device"

Comment: it looks like you want to display your progress dialog in TemperatureActivity then, whilst the device is trying to connect. if unsuccessful you finish() TemperatureActivity.